# Get IP Addresses of 6 devices using MAC addresses using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, network-programming

How do I modify my code to populate a listbox of IP addresses if I know 6 devices MAC addresses?

I am using VB.net to show me my current IP and MAC address but I want to change it to add to a ListBox to show 6 devices on the same network using their MAC addresses. Since we cannot modify the DHCP server, we just want a simple way to show each device's IP address using their known Mac addresses. I will add the MAC addresses in code. but Just want to have the listbox populate on startup of the app.

Existing Code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
        Dim mac As String
        mac = GetMacAddress()
        Label1.Text = mac
    End Sub

    Function GetMacAddress()
        Dim nics() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        Return nics(0).GetPhysicalAddress.ToString
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GetIPv4Address()
    End Sub
    Private Function GetIPv4Address() As String
        GetIPv4Address = String.Empty
        Dim strHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        Dim iphe As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName)

        For Each ipheal As System.Net.IPAddress In iphe.AddressList
            If ipheal.AddressFamily = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                GetIPv4Address = ipheal.ToString()
                Label2.Text = "IP Address: " & ipheal.ToString
            End If
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MAC addresses to IP addresses would requires ARP operations, http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/08/Resolve_IP_Address_And_Host_Name_From_MAC_Address_using_CSharp_and_Windows_ARP_Utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer** - After some more digging, I found untweaked version of the code below [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889483/How-to-List-all-devices-info-on-your-WLAN-router) and tweaked it a bit.

What you end up with is a list of `IpInfo` structures. Each of these objects has the self-explanatory properties of `IpAddress`, `MacAddress` and `HostName`. You can iterate through the list and IP addresses the matching mac addresses to your listbox.

You may need to tweak the `Thread.Sleep` interval to make sure that you get all the results, but I hope this new answer sorts you out.

If it does, I would suggest removing the comments about the code not working so that they don't confuse others looking at this answer.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.Net.Sockets


Public Class Form1

    Structure IpInfo
        Dim IpAddress As String
        Dim HostName As String
        Dim MacAddress As String
    End Structure

    Dim connectedIPAddresses As New List(Of IpInfo)

    Private Shared Function NetworkGateway() As String
        Dim ip As String = Nothing
        For Each f As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            If f.OperationalStatus = OperationalStatus.Up Then
                For Each d As GatewayIPAddressInformation In f.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses
                    ip = d.Address.ToString()
                Next
            End If
        Next
        Return ip
    End Function

    Public Sub Ping_all()
        Dim gate_ip As String = NetworkGateway()
        Dim array As String() = gate_ip.Split("."c)
        For i As Integer = 2 To 255
            Dim ping_var As String = array(0) & "." & array(1) & "." & array(2) & "." & i.ToString
            Ping(ping_var, 1, 1000)
        Next
        Task.WhenAll(taskList)
    End Sub

    Dim taskList As New List(Of Task)

    Public Sub Ping(ByVal host As String, ByVal attempts As Integer, ByVal timeout As Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To attempts - 1
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(Sub()
                                      Try
                                          Dim ping As System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping = New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping()
                                          AddHandler ping.PingCompleted, AddressOf PingCompleted
                                          ping.SendAsync(host, timeout, host)
                                      Catch
                                      End Try
                                  End Sub))
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub PingCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PingCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim ip As String = CStr(e.UserState)
        If e.Reply IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.Reply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
            Dim hostname As String = GetHostName(ip)
            Dim macaddres As String = GetMacAddress(ip)
            Dim newIpAddress As IpInfo
            newIpAddress.IpAddress = ip
            newIpAddress.MacAddress = macaddres
            newIpAddress.HostName = hostname
            connectedIPAddresses.Add(newIpAddress)
        Else
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetHostName(ByVal ipAddress As String) As String
        Try
            Dim entry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress)
            If entry IsNot Nothing Then
                Return entry.HostName
            End If
        Catch __unusedSocketException1__ As SocketException
        End Try

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function GetMacAddress(ByVal ipAddress As String) As String
        Dim macAddress As String = String.Empty
        Dim Process As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = "arp"
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " & ipAddress
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Process.Start()
        Dim strOutput As String = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        Dim substrings As String() = strOutput.Split("-"c)
        If substrings.Length >= 8 Then
            macAddress = substrings(3).Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings(3).Length - 2)) & "-" & substrings(4) & "-" & substrings(5) & "-" & substrings(6) & "-" & substrings(7) & "-" + substrings(8).Substring(0, 2)
            Return macAddress
        Else
            Return "OWN Machine"
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Ping_all()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
        For Each ip As IpInfo In connectedIPAddresses
            ListBox1.Items.Add(ip.IpAddress)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that code didn't produce proper results. 6 lines that were added:
"APPNAME.Form2+NetworkInterfaceInfo"

Comment: @CJDronePilot I've updated the answer. The code isn't instantaneous, but it does seem to work.

Comment: Slight error when running code: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

HERE:
`Dim ping_var As String = array(0) & "." & array(1) & "." & array(2) & "." & i.ToString
            Ping(ping_var, 1, 1000)`

Comment: Sounds like a network problem. Maybe a firewall, or other security settings on a device/router.  When the Line ` Dim array As String() = gate_ip.Split("."c)` executes, it should return an ip address. If no ip address is returned then you end up with an empty string. Then when it is split, there are not enough elements in the array that is created from the split, so you'll end up with an IndexOutOfRangeExcepetion, because the line that the error occurs on is trying to access array elements that don't exist. I would suggest having a chat with whoever administer the network and security. Sorry